# getting value from elements created dynamically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

im working on  a project(UWP C sharp) from college..
i need to build library program that manege books and magazines
i have a problem with the edit item page...
iv created method that create elements (text box, datepicker , etc..)  dynamically by the type of the item that selected (if the user select book, he'll get the elements for book same for magazines..)
the problem is when im trying to write the event button that take the values from all those elements i cant reach them... cuz they in a method..
 (like book.title = textbox.text;)

sorry for my English and Ty for the help:)

```
 private void CreateBtnsByTheTypeOfTheItem(AbstractItem item)
        {
            TextBox editTitleTB = new TextBox();
            editTitleTB.Text = LibManager.Instance.CurrentItem.Title;
            Grid.SetRow(editTitleTB, 0);
            editPageGrid.Children.Add(editTitleTB);

            CheckBox editIsAvaibleCB = new CheckBox();
            editIsAvaibleCB.Content = "Is Avaible";
            editIsAvaibleCB.IsChecked = item.isAvaible;
            Grid.SetRow(editIsAvaibleCB, 1);
            editPageGrid.Children.Add(editIsAvaibleCB);

            DatePicker editDatePicler = new DatePicker();
            editDatePicler.Date = item.PublishDate;
            Grid.SetRow(editDatePicler, 3);
            editPageGrid.Children.Add(editDatePicler);



            if (item is Book)
            {
                Book itemAsBook = item as Book;

                TextBox editAuthor = new TextBox();
                editAuthor.Text = itemAsBook.Author;
                Grid.SetRow(editAuthor, 2);
                editPageGrid.Children.Add(editAuthor);

                var _enumval = Enum.GetValues(typeof(BookCategory)).Cast<BookCategory>();

                ComboBox editCategpryCB = new ComboBox();
                editCategpryCB.ItemsSource = _enumval.ToList();
                editCategpryCB.SelectedItem = itemAsBook.Category;
                Grid.SetRow(editCategpryCB, 4);
                editPageGrid.Children.Add(editCategpryCB);
            }
            else
            {
                Magazine itemAsMagazine = item as Magazine;

                TextBox editEditors = new TextBox();
                editEditors.Text = itemAsMagazine.Editors;
                Grid.SetRow(editEditors, 2);
                editPageGrid.Children.Add(editEditors);

                var _enumval = Enum.GetValues(typeof(MagazineCategory)).Cast<MagazineCategory>();

                ComboBox editMagazineCategory = new ComboBox();
                editMagazineCategory.ItemsSource = _enumval.ToList();
                editMagazineCategory.SelectedItem = itemAsMagazine.Category;
                Grid.SetRow(editMagazineCategory, 4);
                editPageGrid.Children.Add(editMagazineCategory);
            }
```

Comment: "cuz they in a method" , not sure I follow... but if I am following you at all, it's just a matter of scope, so just store your data in a dictionary/list, make it static, or public in a class, and reference it that way.

Comment: they didn't teach us about dictionary yet...
i wanna know if i can get values from those elemnts some how i know i cant reach them cuz they live only inside the method

Comment: I think you are looking for: editPageGrid.Children

Comment: tried that, dosent work... cuz still they live only inside the method even if i called that method in the mainpage he need to know before runing that hes got those elements for sure...

Comment: Good luck, I have no idea what we are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If you have named each of the dynamically created field you can access them by using the FindName method.

```
TextBox editTitleTB = new TextBox();
editTitleTB.Name = "TheHobbitTB";
editTitleTB.Text = LibManager.Instance.CurrentItem.Title;
TextBox theHobbitTB = (TextBox)this.FindName("TheHobbitTB");
```

Then you could essentially edit what ever you want about this specific textbox.